# JSON Schema validation on dictionary of lists with unknown length

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that is in the form below

```
{
"flows": [
    {
        "item1": ""
    }
]}
```

I have the schema written to validate this but it only validates it if there is one item in the list. My problem is that that list can have as many items as the user wants. My "flows" item can have item1, item2, ... itemX.

Is this possible? And if so, how can it be done? Below is the schema I'm working with

```
{
"definitions": {},
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#", 
"$id": "https://example.com/object1678205540.json", 
"title": "Root", 
"type": "object",
"required": [
    "flows"
],
"properties": {
    "flows": {
        "$id": "#root/flows", 
        "title": "Flows", 
        "type": "array",
        "default": [],
        "items":{
            "$id": "#root/flows/items", 
            "title": "Items", 
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "item1"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "item1": {
                    "$id": "#root/flows/items/item1", 
                    "title": "Item1", 
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "",
                    "pattern": "^.*$"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}}
```

This does verify the schema correctly but if I add in an item2 or item3, etc. it will fail. I don't know the amount of items in the list and I obviously don't want to just have a schema that is 1000+ lines long to cover all the options. Is there a way to loop the schema? Or make it so that the schema can be generalized without splitting my JSON apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pattern Properties](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#id4) allow defining accepted property names based on regex patterns.  The [Additional Properties](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#id5) flag allows rejecting undefined properties.

Adjusted Schema:

```
{
"definitions": {},
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#", 
"$id": "https://example.com/object1678205540.json", 
"title": "Root", 
"type": "object",
"required": [
    "flows"
],
"properties": {
    "flows": {
        "$id": "#root/flows", 
        "title": "Flows", 
        "type": "array",
        "default": [],
        "items":{
            "$id": "#root/flows/items", 
            "title": "Items", 
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "item1"
            ],
            "patternProperties": {
                "^item[0-9]+$": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "",
                    "pattern": "^.*$"
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    }
}}
```

JSON Data:

```
{
"flows": [
    {
        "item1": "A1",
        "item2": "A2"
    }
}

{
"flows": [
    {
        "item1": "A1",
        "item2": "A2",
        "reject": "X"  <<< ERROR - additional property
    },
    {                  <<< ERROR - item1 property required
        "item2": "B1",
        "item3": "B2",
    }
]}
```